# Why is AppUser null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello guys I have a problem with my asp.net core project. So I built the Register form and I retrieve data of the user from the Register view but When I click a submit button  Nothing happened and I seeing appUser is null
Please Help me[image]

```
public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View(new UserSignUpViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserSignUpViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUsers appUsers = new AppUsers();

                appUsers.Name = model.Name;
                appUsers.UserName = model.UserName;
                appUsers.SurName = model.SurName;
                
               
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUsers, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: You probably need to share your AppUsers class

Comment: `appUsers` is not null in your image, but `appUsers.Name` is, since it hasn't been assigned any value yet

Comment: I gave value from register form

Comment: at the time you debug, the `Name` ***has not been set*** to the model's data yet. That's so obvious. What you need to inspect on is the `model.Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine but you need to check your Model binding in view.

Answer (score 2):

The attached screenshot demonstrates the state **prior** to the assignment. For this reason the `appUsers.Name` is not set yet (and hence is null). The `appUsers` object is not null, otherwise you would've had a `NullReferenceException` on this line. Just jump into the next line and see `appUsers.Name` populated with `model.Name` value.